# Adding additional repository to Maven 3

Tags: java, maven, com4j

I want to add to my project some special dependeny from some repository.

For this I add the repository in my pom:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jenkins-repo</id>
        <name>Jenkins Repository</name>
        <url>maven.jenkins-ci.org/content/repositories/releases</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

.. and in the same file add the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.com4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>com4j</artifactId>
    <version>20120426-2</version>
</dependency>
```

But it doesn't work: the dependency is not found. As far as I understand this proves that the dependency exists in the right place:
http://maven.jenkins-ci.org/content/repositories/releases/org/jvnet/com4j/com4j/20120426-2/

So here are the questions:

1) Where I went wrong?

2) If I add repository to pom the default repository still be checked?

3) The link provided is really a link to Maven repo which proves I can download an artifact from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `<url>` to include protocol

```
<url>http://maven.jenkins-ci.org/content/repositories/releases</url>
```